# Search Name Like Query in JPA

Tags: spring-boot

I have a table that contains above 50k records and I want to search name of company like %abc% but always get `index out of range`: 0

Tried with
Native query

```
@Query(value="select * from company where name like '%:keyword%'", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Company> getByName(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

JPA Method:

```
public List<Company> findByNameContaining(String name);
public List<Company> findByNameLike(String name);
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: No, It won't work for large data

Comment: @RahulSuryawanshi, what do you mean by "won't work for large data"? You are using a `LIKE` query that scans whole table. What exactly is wrong with the answer in the comment section?

Comment: is above code work if you give exact same name from DB and is query able to return single record?

Comment: you could try `name like :keyword` and pass complete `%needle%` as input param

Answer (score 0):

The “TypeError: string index out of range” error is raised when you try to access an item at an index position that does not exist. You solve this error by making sure that your code treats strings as if they are indexed from the position 0.